# Insert \n after the word after a regex match

Tags: regex, r

Let's say I have a long string of text, like a paragraph or more, and there is a specific word that appears frequently, lets call it KEY.

I want to insert a "\n" after the word that comes after each KEY.

So if I have the string `KEY Hello this is KEY an example`. I want it to look like `KEY Hello \nthis is KEY an \nexample`

If the task were slightly simpler, and I just wanted to add \n after KEY then I could easily do that with, `gsub("KEY","KEY \n",string)`, but I don't think regex has an elegant way of selecting the word after a match, and even if it did I'm not sure I could use it in a `gsub`.

What would be a good way to add the \n's where I want them?

Comment: Use a capture group and refer to it? `gsub("(KEY .+? )", "\\1\n", string)`.  Or more general `gsub("(KEY[., ;!?].+? )", "\\1\n", string)`.  Putting whatever punctuation you want in the character class part `[., ;!?]`

Comment: Carl, you are oversimplifying. What about `Some KEY, next word`? What if there is no space after the "next" word? And what is a *word* for you? 1+ alphanumeric/underscore (`\w+`)? Or just ASCII letters with hyphen and apostrophe `[a-zA-Z'-]+`?

Comment: @Jota That worked perfectly. I'll accept it if you make it an answer

Comment: To improve on Jota's suggestion and avoid unnecessary backtracking, I'd recommend `gsub("(KEY\\s+\\S+\\s*)", "\\1\n", string)` - it will also work if there are no spaces after the "next" word.

Comment: Or even [`gsub("(KEY\\W+\\w+\\s*)", "\\1\n", string)`](https://regex101.com/r/zN3tF5/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group and refer back to it.  You have to decide how to handle certain scenarios and the specifics of your case, as Wiktor Stribiżew pointed out.

For the example case presented, look for KEY followed by a space followed by non-whitepspace characters 1 or more times (`\\S+`) followed by a space:

```
gsub("(KEY \\S+ )", "\\1\n", string, perl = TRUE)
```

If you want to be more general in what can follow "KEY", then you can add a character class including what you'll allow (or \s for any whitespace character or \W for any non-alphanumeric/underscore characters, as Wiktor points out).  Something like this:

```
gsub("(KEY[., ;!?]\\S+ )", "\\1\n", string, perl = TRUE)
gsub("(KEY\\s\\S+ )", "\\1\n", string, perl = TRUE)
gsub("(KEY\\W+\\S+ )", "\\1\n", string, perl = TRUE)
```

Putting whatever punctuation you want in the character class part `[., ;!?]`

---

Wiktor's variation(s) may be a bit more robust:

```
gsub("(KEY\\s+\\S+\\s*)", "\\1\n", string)  # \s = white-space character
                                            # \S = non-white-space character
gsub("(KEY\\W+\\w+\\s*)", "\\1\n", string) # \w for alphanumeric/underscore
                                           # \W for the opposite of \w.
```

These variants don't require a space after the next word (`\\s*` for 0 or more white-space characters) and they can match one or more whitespace characters after KEY or one or more non-alphanumerics/underscores after KEY.

Comment: In this case, there is no need using a lazy quantifier after `\S`, just use `\S+` (shorter, same performance).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! mind if I include your variant in my answer?

Comment: As you wish, it is a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. None of these work if there is more than one space after KEY. How would you adjust to make "KEY    word" into "KEY    word\n"? (note: there should be extra spaces between KEY and word

Comment: @Carl `gsub("(KEY\\s+\\S+\\s*)", "\\1\n", string)` and `gsub("(KEY\\W+\\w+\\s*)", "\\1\n", string)` both work when there are one or more spaces after KEY.  The `+` means one or more.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're saying, because multiple of the solutions can handle multiple spaces after KEY.